# Problem with database version for drupal 9 db upgrade

Tags: database

Hi I am trying to upgrade drupal 9 on godaddy and when I go to update.php I get this note on the screen...

DATABASE SYSTEM VERSION
5.6.51-cll-lve
The database server version 5.6.51-cll-lve is less than the minimum required version 5.7.8.

Godaddy told me they support only 5.6 version. Is there a workaround or we need to change host?

Comment: You need to change host

Answer (score 2):

There’s no need to change host right away, you can install the [mysql56 module](https://www.drupal.org/project/mysql56) which gives support up to at least Drupal 9.3.

Support won’t continue forever, so it would be a good idea to start making plans to move to a host with more up to date software.